# ReferenceError throws in react js arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the normal function below. It was working fine.

```js
function getCheck(result, orderBy) {
  return result === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => compareFunction(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -compareFunction(a, b, orderBy);
}
```

I tried to rewrite like below but got the error message instead:

> ReferenceError: a is not defined

```js
function getCheck(result, orderBy) {
  if (result === 'desc') {
    return compareFunction(a, b, orderBy);
  } else if (result === 'asc') {
    return compareFunction(a, b, orderBy);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

How to rewrite the above function without error?

Comment: I believe you might have left a bug here. Your first code snippet under else condition adds a `-` to invert the order I believe. The refactored doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code it was returning a new function from the `getCheck` function. But in your rewritten code you are returning the result of executing `compareFunction`. You can not write that without error. If you want to invoke the `compareFunction` with a and b you have to define them.

In case of the first code you are returing a function defintion, hence you don't have to declare the variable `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
function getCheck(result, orderBy) {
    if(result === 'desc') {
        return  (a,b) => compareFunction(a, b, orderBy)
    }else if(result === 'asc') {
        return  (a,b) => compareFunction(a, b, orderBy)
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

var a = obj1
var b = obj2
getCheck("desc", "name")(a ,b)
```